# Traduction de core dans un contexte particulier

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, santé-et-médecine

Je participe à la traduction d'un site anlgais et plus généralement à la passation de connaissances de la communauté anglophone à la communauté français sur le sommeil polyphasique et je bloque sur l'adaptation d'un mot, le *core*.

Pour avoir un peu de contexte, le sommeil polyphasique consiste à fragmenter son cycle de sommeil en plusieurs parties au lieu d'une seule (par exemple, dormir 4h30 puis faire 2 sieste de 20 minutes dans la journée).

En anglais, on parlera alors de *nap* (20 minutes) et de *core* (>1h30).

La traduction de *core* est généralement *noyau*, mais peut-être aussi le *cœur* ou *l'essentiel*.
Cependant ici, aucun de ces termes ne correspond tout à fait. La traduction la plus compréhensible serait *la partie principale*, mais c'est long et parfois peu pratique, surtout quand on mentionne ce terme couramment.

Je suis donc à la recherche d'une alternative si quelqu'un en a une à proposer.

Exemple:

> Before repartitioning the naps will not contain REM, and one will only enter SWS if sleep deprived. The **core** will also have a significant portion of light sleep. During adaptation the body will slowly start trading off light sleep for quality sleep in the **core**
>
> REM deprivation typically happens on any reduced-sleep schedule, while SWS deprivation is typically only problematic with schedules that have less than 3 **core** cycles (nominally 4.5h of **core** time).
>
> **Core** placement matters because most schedules rely on **cores** exclusively for SWS sleep. **Core** length till alarm matters because you definitely want to wake in light sleep every time

Comment: As-tu une source pour que l'on voit plus de contexte ? Sinon le cœur du sommeille peu être cohérent si c'est la partie du sommeille la plus importante.

Comment: j'en ai ajouté @BaptisteGavalda

Comment: La traduction va donc dépendre de la phrase. Tu peux, je pense, utiliser "cœur", "base" ou enCORE (pardon) "principale"

Comment: je pense qu'on va partir sur ça, en s'arrangeant pour faire comprendre qu'on parle bien de la même chose.

Comment: Je pense que la traduction la plus cohérente serait "la phase principale du sommeil", bien que vous essayez d'éviter l'utilisation de ce éot

Answer (score 3):

Quel que soit le mot, s'il n'est pas spécialisé il y aura la possibilité qu'il devienne gênant de par la proximité des sens connexes de la forme qu'il incarne avec des concepts incidents. Un terme possible, de cette sorte-là (non spécialisé), est « **base** »;

- une base de 4 h 30 et 2 siestes de 20 mn

Si l'on veut dire maintenant « Sur une base de 90 jours consécutifs de ce régime de sommeil », évidemment, on est un peu gêné.

Une autre possibilité est le mot « **assise** ».

- une assise de 4 h 30 mn et 2 siestes de 20 mn

Il y a le substantif « **principal** » (en analogie avec le substantif « principal » signifiant « capital » ou « personne la plus importante », mais l'adjectif homographe est utilisé souvent.

On peut envisager un emprunt à l'anglais, et utiliser le mot « **bulk** », et alors on est tout de suite plus libre.

Comment: Je retiens les propositions et je vais les tester. Petite remarque cependant, si l'on doit emprunter à l'anglais, autant garder le terme original de **core**, je pense.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
<sup><sup>Polyphasic Society pour fins d'illustration</sup></sup>

Avec deux *cores* et une sieste par exemple, on peut penser aux *principales périodes/séquences de sommeil*, par rapport à celles qui sont secondaires, ou *aux périodes/séquences prolongées de sommeil* ou *aux longues périodes/séquences* (de sommeil), par opposition à celles qui sont de courtes durées (les siestes). Je pense aussi à *blocs (de sommeil)*, avec *longs...*, *grands...* ou encore *...prolongés* ; plus généralement aux *moments de sommeil* dans l'horaire. Bien des combinaisons mais assurément plus longues que le mot *core* ! *Séquence(s)* ?

[*Noms* : ...Moment, période, séquence, bloc, segment, éventement...]
[Adjectifs : ...principal, significatif, majeur, prolongé, long, grand...]
[...de sommeil...]

Comment: L'idée est intéressante, cependant je ne cherche pas la traduction du mot *core* mais de *l'idée* que le core transmet dans ce contexte, qui est la phase de sommeil supérieure à 1h30 (à opposer à la sieste qui doit être de 20 minutes). 
De la même façon qu'en Anglais le *core sleep* (sommeil princinpal auquel tu fais référence) est différent du *core* (qui fait référence à la partie principale du cycle polyphasique), ici le mot sommeil principal désigne ce que tu décris, et pourrais décrire en effet ce que je recherche.

Comment: Je vais tester pour voir si la répétition des 2 termes (comme la répétition de core en anglais, dans le contexte classique et celui du sommeil polyphasique) n'est pas gênante. Elle pourrait en l'occurence être intéressante pour garder la similitude à l'anglais

Comment: Il n'y a pas de problème. Le terme *bloc* est intéressant, mais j'ai peur qu'il soit confus comme un *bloc* pourrait être aussi intérpréter comme un *core* mais aussi comme une *sieste*/*nap*

Comment: @JackRed Comme j'avais indiqué j'étais certain qu'il s'agissait d'une abréviation pour _core sleep_. Maintenant que je pense avoir compris ce dont il s'agit, j'ai modifié ma réponse, qui va peut-être en inspirer d'autres... Je comprends ton souci d'éviter la confusion avec les siestes. Par ailleurs j'ai noté que dans certains scénarios comme dymaxion toutes les séquences ressemblent (30 mins) à des siestes, dis-tu sieste ou _core_ dans ce cas-là ? Avec _partie principale_ je pense que tu es sur la bonne voie aussi.

Comment: Les cycles comme dymaxion ou uberman sont dit *nap-only*, et donc n'ont pas de *core*.